# how can I implement pixel tracker in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer, tracking-pixel

I implement NodeJS api from what user can send multiple emails to multiple contacts (nodemailer), I want to track open rate, I test this from my localhost by inserting 1px image in html body with src call for server route : `<img src="http://1xx.xxx.x.xx:4001/v1/users/google-tracker"/>` but nothing happen in my server side when I open mail, no call for this route !!!
anybody have an idea about the problem ? is it google who's blocking that ??

Comment: Many email clients will NOT display embedded image links without intervention from the user exactly to foil tracking like this.  What email client are you trying this with?

Comment: I'm testing this scenario : I connect to api my gmail user (oAuth2) and I try to send emails to contacts im my DB (through nodemailer conf for gmail service), I want to get data about who opened my email